# kivy: the apk built by buildozer didn't work

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

After I packaged my kivy app as an apk, when I ran it on android, it showed a black screen and didn't get any errors. However, when I run on python, the program does not make an error.
This is my `main.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class FiveChessGame(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FiveChessGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.buttons = []  
        self.current_player = "X"  
        self.result_label = Label(text="", font_size=20)
        self.add_widget(self.result_label)
        
        board_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        board_layout.size_hint = (None, None)
        board_layout.size = (800, 500)
        for _ in range(15):
            row_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            row_buttons = []
            for _ in range(15):
                button = Button()
                button.bind(on_release=self.on_button_click)
                row_buttons.append(button)
                row_layout.add_widget(button)
            self.buttons.append(row_buttons)
            board_layout.add_widget(row_layout)
        self.add_widget(board_layout)

    def on_button_click(self, button):
        if button.text == "":
            button.text = self.current_player
            if self.check_winner():
                self.result_label.text = f"{self.current_player} win！"
                for row in self.buttons:
                    for btn in row:
                        btn.unbind(on_release=self.on_button_click)
            else:
                self.current_player = "O" if self.current_player == "X" else "X"

    def check_winner(self):
        lines = []
        for row in range(15):
            lines.append([self.buttons[row][col].text for col in range(15)])
        for col in range(15):
            lines.append([self.buttons[row][col].text for row in range(15)])
        for offset in range(-10, 11):
            lines.append([self.buttons[row + offset][row].text for row in range(max(-offset, 0), min(15, 15 - offset))])
            lines.append([self.buttons[row + offset][14 - row].text for row in range(max(-offset, 0), min(15, 15 - offset))])

        for line in lines:
            for i in range(len(line) - 4):
                if line[i:i + 5] == ["X"] * 5 or line[i:i + 5] == ["O"] * 5:
                    return True
        return False

class FiveChessApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = FiveChessGame()
        return game

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FiveChessApp().run()
```

This is what it looks like on python:
[running on python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6rFD.png)

Please help me solve the problem!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).